# Uncommented img´s not showing unless resizing browser, zooming or opening dev tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im using a uncommenting method for lazy loading my images. I have my reason to and it works well except that I need to resizing browser, zooming or open dev tools in order to make them show up. I think the elements refresh when I do that. Is there any way to simulate any of the 3 actions via javascript or any way to make the images in my .container div refresh?

So here is the Jquery im using:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.uncomment = function(recurse) {
        $(this).contents().each(function() {
            if ( recurse && this.hasChildNodes() ) {
                $(this).uncomment(recurse);
            } else if ( this.nodeType == 8 ) {
                var e = $('<span>' + this.nodeValue + '</span>');
                $(this).replaceWith(e.contents());
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

and on click the images should start to appear which they do but only when slightly resizing the window:

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#music').uncomment(/* recurse */ true );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `translate` to content:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.uncomment = function(recurse) {
        $(this).contents().each(function() {
            if ( recurse && this.hasChildNodes() ) {
                $(this).uncomment(recurse);
            } else if ( this.nodeType == 8 ) {
                var e = $('<span>' + this.nodeValue + '</span>');
                $(this).replaceWith(e.contents());
                $(this).css({'translateX' : 0});
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Or trigger `resize` event on window

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.uncomment = function(recurse) {
        $(this).contents().each(function() {
            if ( recurse && this.hasChildNodes() ) {
                $(this).uncomment(recurse);
            } else if ( this.nodeType == 8 ) {
                var e = $('<span>' + this.nodeValue + '</span>');
                $(this).replaceWith(e.contents());
            }
            $(window).trigger('resize');
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Doesnt work. I tried all css properties and non of them triggered their appearance. Only resizing my browser, zooming or opening dev tools.

Comment: Hi Bogdan, that didnt work either. Want me to create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Weird, it works here, maybe because im using the picture element from html5

Comment: Ok, now when adding the following at the end of my source media="(min-width: 0px)"> it works but using max width it doesnt